# Example domain class for a Web Crawler Using Grails and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, grails, dns, web-crawler

I am making a web crawler using Groovy on Grails and MongoDB at the backend. I am unsure of how to model the domain class for the same.

Ex:

Domain Class Website contains websites that user has presaved and wants to crawl.
Model website contains : www.google.com
After Crawling www.google.com I get following information:

```
www.a.com   resource types  other metrics
www.b.com   resource types  other metrics
www.c.com   resource types  other metrics
www.d.com   resource types  other metrics
```

I want to store them in database and continue crawling. Again, www.a.com when crawled will yield more urls like :

```
www.a1.com  resource types  other metrics
www.a2.com  resource types  other metrics
```

Similarly for all other urls, they would have child URLs. How can I model a domain class for it? One idea that I have is have a domain class(that will have an association with itself) as follows but I am not sure if its the right approach:

```
    class Resource implements Comparable { 
       String url
       String otherMetrics
       SortedSet subResources
       static hasMany = [subResources: Resource]
       static belongsTo = [parent: Resource]
}
```

Comment: down voters please give the reason for your downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code doesn't work because you forget the mappedBy part:

You'll probably need the next line to get it work:

```
static mappedBy = [subResources:'parent']
```

At the end, it is a tree, and I use the same approach for this kind of problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to know somebody else had the same approach for this problem. Thanks. I will try this :)